# imacros - how extract form name

Tags: html, forms, imacros, names

i'm trying to create a script that extract the form name and save it in a variable... how can i do it?

i tryed read the official wiki but i can't understand it very well... i need only the form name

this is my code

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
PROMPT "Please enter text" !VAR1
URL GOTO=https://www.facebook.com/groups/231483473723160/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:u_0_1j ATTR=ID:u_0_1n CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=TXT:Publicar
WAIT SECONDS=2
```

the form id changes every time, my idea is extract the form id before of posting and save it on a variable, after that change the code with the saved id...

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to get ‘id’ of the first (‘POS=1’) form on the web-page and set variable ‘formId’ to its value:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=FORM ATTR=ID:* EXTRACT=HTM
SET formId EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".match(/<form[^>]*id=[\"\']([^\"^\']*)[\"\']*[>\\s]/i)[1];")
```

Comment: uow! thanks! but i need help one more time please... how can i use the value from the last line? i can't figure it out... i need to put this in this line TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:******* ATTR=ID:u_0_1n CONTENT=test, when *** is where i need to put this... can you help me please?

Comment: No problem. `TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:{{formId}} ATTR=ID:u_0_1n CONTENT=test`